# stdClass PHP access array not working

Tags: php, arrays, soap

Trying to access the objects in this array. I followed the

[stdClass Object foreach PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934327/stdclass-object-foreach-php)

No matter what I try I can't get what I need out of the array.

The only thing that does work is

```
 echo $response->TotalResults;
```

That gives me the value of 18. Great but when I try

```
  echo $response->Call[0]->ToNumber->_;
```

or

```
 echo $response->Call->CallRecord->Result;
```

It returns blank

I have tried a foreach loop from the other posting:

```
    foreach($responses->TotalResults as $value){
       foreach($value->Call as $obj){
         echo $obj->FromNumber;
        }
echo $value->name;
  }
```

Returns nothing. I really didn't find anything that would help on the php site that would help guide me in what to do to retrieve data from this kind of array. Below is the sample array of data.

```
    object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
   ["TotalResults"]=> int(18)
   ["Call"]=>  array(18) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#9 (12) {
          ["FromNumber"]=>
          string(11) "17575551211"
          ["ToNumber"]=>
          object(stdClass)#10 (1) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(11) "17575554039"
          }
              ["State"]=>
              string(8) "FINISHED"
              ["BatchId"]=>
              int(33236)
              ["BroadcastId"]=>
              int(1069425001)
              ["ContactId"]=>
              float(836743)
              ["Inbound"]=>
              bool(false)
              ["Created"]=>
              string(20) "2013-08-09T15:24:11Z"
              ["Modified"]=>
              string(20) "2013-08-11T13:16:54Z"
              ["FinalResult"]=>
              string(2) "LA"
              ["id"]=>
              float(1001389)
       ["CallRecord"]=>
              array(2) {
            [0]=>
            object(stdClass)#11 (7) {
              ["Result"]=>
              string(2) "LA"
              ["FinishTime"]=>
              string(20) "2013-08-11T13:16:51Z"
              ["BilledAmount"]=>
              float(1.6667)
              ["QuestionResponse"]=>
              object(stdClass)#12 (2) {
                ["Question"]=>
                string(4) "Q1R1"
                ["Response"]=>
                string(7) "Confirm"
              }
              ["id"]=>
              float(572965)
              ["AnswerTime"]=>
              string(20) "2013-08-11T13:16:22Z"
              ["Duration"]=>
              int(29)
            }
            [1]=>
            object(stdClass)#13 (6) {
              ["Result"]=>
              string(6) "NO_ANS"
              ["FinishTime"]=>
              string(20) "2013-08-11T13:01:05Z"
              ["BilledAmount"]=>
              float(0)
              ["id"]=>
              float(57296503001)
              ["OriginateTime"]=>
              string(20) "2013-08-11T13:00:02Z"
              ["Duration"]=>
              int(0)
    }
  }
}
            [1]=>
            object(stdClass)#14 (12) {
              ["FromNumber"]=>
              string(11) "17575557998"
              ["ToNumber"]=>
              object(stdClass)#15 (1) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(11) "17575557255"
              }
              ["State"]=>
              string(8) "FINISHED"
              ["BatchId"]=>
              int(332369)
              ["BroadcastId"]=>
              int(1069425)
              ["ContactId"]=>
              float(83674367)
              ["Inbound"]=>
              bool(false)
              ["Created"]=>
              string(20) "2013-08-09T15:24:11Z"
              ["Modified"]=>
              string(20) "2013-08-11T13:03:17Z"
              ["FinalResult"]=>
              string(2) "LA"
              ["id"]=>
              float(100138916)
                ["CallRecord"]=>
          object(stdClass)#16 (6) {
            ["Result"]=>
            string(2) "LA"
            ["FinishTime"]=>
            string(20) "2013-08-11T13:03:13Z"
            ["BilledAmount"]=>
            float(5.0001)
            ["id"]=>
            float(57296546)
            ["AnswerTime"]=>
            string(20) "2013-08-11T13:00:35Z"
            ["Duration"]=>
            int(158)
          }
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#17 (12) {
          ["FromNumber"]=>
          string(11) "17575557998"
          ["ToNumber"]=>
          object(stdClass)#18 (1) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(11) "17575552158"
          }
          ["State"]=>
          string(8) "FINISHED"
          ["BatchId"]=>
          int(332369)
          ["BroadcastId"]=>
          int(106942)
          ["ContactId"]=>
          float(83674)
          ["Inbound"]=>
          bool(false)
          ["Created"]=>
          string(20) "2013-08-09T15:24:11Z"
          ["Modified"]=>
          string(20) "2013-08-11T13:03:15Z"
          ["FinalResult"]=>
          string(2) "LA"
          ["id"]=>
          float(100138)

             }
          }
       }
```

Any help on how to access the array would be great.
Regards

Comment: `echo $response->Call[0]->ToNumber->{'_'};` and `echo $response->Call->CallRecord[0]->Result;`

Comment: I tried both of these and neither of them worked. Thanks for trying!

Comment: I must retract my last statement and say that the two statements work.