# how to print values if we have an assoc array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter.
Structure of my array is

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 14
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 14
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

)
```

I want to print the value of arrays.

Comment: look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `foreach` for access all

```
foreach ($array as $values)
{
   foreach ($values as $value)
   {
      echo $value;
   }
}
```

#### Or direct access:

```
$array[0]->{1};
$array[0]->{2};
$array[1]->{5};
etc..
```

**Usage:**

```
$array[ARRAY INDEX]->{OBJECT INDEX};
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as they are not arrays but objects, you need to use

```
$arr[0]->{0}
```

form.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array is in the variable `$arr`. Then use it:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $array){
 echo $array[$i];
 $i++;
}
```

OR you can do this:

```
echo $arr[1]->0; //and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get data using

```
$arr[0]->{0}
```

OR

```
$arr[0]->{'0'}
```

Answer (score 0):

stdClass is php's generic empty class, kind of like Object in Java or object in Python. It is useful for anonymous objects, dynamic properties, etc.

So its not array its an object. you will have to use object operator (->)

check below post

[stdClass Object foreach PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934327/stdclass-object-foreach-php)